# How to make this kind of horizontal animation while vertical scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make horizontal animation like this one (cars riding on the road by scroll)

https://prime-logistik.at/en/fleet/ .

Unfortunately, this animation in my example was made by the WordPress plugin. I have made CSS parallax effect by "fixed background" method and have tried to make cars like progress bars, but it doesn't work well. I've tried to find plugins for this, but no one of them does exactly the same kind of animation.

Can you please name the plugin/plugins or another way to do it in general?

jQuery and pure js are very welcome. I've made an example here codepen.io/yourniceshot/pen/JjbpWxm .

My problem is, that if I use an absolute position of the car element, it moves along with the background and if I use a fixed position, the car element is obviously above everything

Comment: You need to show us the code you have tried so far and to describe what 'doesn't work well' means in more detail. SO doesn't like questions which ask for software recommendations so rephrase your question as a coding one to get better help.

Comment: Your example is using this lib : https://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/ , it's pretty useful if you want to make easy scrolling effects

Comment: I've made an example here https://codepen.io/yourniceshot/pen/JjbpWxm . my problem is, that if I use an absolute position of the car element, it moves along with the background and if I use a fixed position, the car element is obviously above everything :c